# extract a specific line from a huge repetititve file with a particular regex

Tags: regex, linux, awk

I have a huge file with this format:

```
Sequence

xxxxx 12  161
xxxxx 54  148
Sequence

hhhhh 4   110
gsgsgs 8   88
Sequence

jjjjj 1   45
skskkak 5  8
```

And so on...
I just want a file with the first complete line after the word "sequence" (note that after that word there is a blank space). That is:

```
xxxxx 12  161
hhhhh 4   110
jjjjj 1   45
```

Any help, please? I thought to do it with awk, but I do not use frequently so I am a bit lost with regex...

Comment: Is ther always one blank line after `Sequence` or can it be more?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
sequence\s*([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)
```

You can try this with `grep -P` .See demo.grab the capture.

http://regex101.com/r/lZ5mN8/30

Comment: This depends on the version of grep. On cygwin, old version of grep (2.5) will search across lines, while newer version won't.

Answer (score 1):

**`Sed`** solution would be like

```
$ sed -n '/Sequence/{n;n;p}' test
xxxxx 12  161
hhhhh 4   110
jjjjj 1   45
```

If you want **`awk`** you can try

```
$ awk '/Sequence/{getline; getline; print}' test
xxxxx 12  161
hhhhh 4   110
jjjjj 1   45
```

**OR**

much shorter

```
awk '/Sequence/{x=NR+2}NR==x'
```

Thanks to  Jidder for the suggestion

Comment: For people that don't like getline  `awk '/Sequence/{x=NR+2}NR==x' file`

Answer (score 1):

You can used `'^(?=Sequence).*\n+^$\n+\K(^.*$)'` pattern to match those text.

```
$ grep -Pzo '^(?=Sequence).*\n+^$\n+\K(^.*$)' file.txt 
xxxxx 12  161
hhhhh 4   110
jjjjj 1   45
```

Here `\K` causes the preceding pattern to match and not print it.

You can look at it in realtime [here](http://regex101.com/r/iF3hW8/1)

Comment: just this regex `grep -Pzo '^Sequence\n\n\K.*' file` would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable as a flag in [`awk`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html)

```
awk '/Sequence/{f=1;next}f==1&&NF>0{f=0;print}'
```

- `/Sequence/{f=1;next}` on a line matching `/Sequence/` set flag `f` and skip to the next line
- `f==1&&NR>0{f=0;print}` on the first non empty line unset flag `f` and print the line

Comment: Think you mean `NF` not `NR` :)

Comment: Also could be shortened to `awk 'f&&NF{f=0;print}/Sequence/{f=1}'` or even `awk 'f&&NF&&f--;/Sequence/{f=1}'`